# Can't show android dialog

Tags: java, android, layout, dialog

I've created a dialog and am having trouble showing it inside my main activity's on create method.
I'm calling `show` on the object like this:

```
FireMissilesDialogFragment newFragment = new FireMissilesDialogFragment();
newFragment.show();
```

But I get an error saying that it `can't resolve method 'show'`

This is my Dialog code (I'm learning how to make them so this is a copy from android dev site dialog training)

```
package com.shush;

import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.app.Dialog;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.DialogFragment;


public class FireMissilesDialogFragment extends DialogFragment {
    @Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Use the Builder class for convenient dialog construction
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
        builder.setMessage(R.string.name)
                .setPositiveButton(R.string.name, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                        // FIRE ZE MISSILES!
                    }
                })
                .setNegativeButton(R.string.address, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                        // User cancelled the dialog
                    }
                });
        // Create the AlertDialog object and return it
        return builder.create();
    }
}
```

Comment: What are extending Activity class from?

Answer (score 1):

Instead of

```
  FireMissilesDialogFragment newFragment = new FireMissilesDialogFragment();
  newFragment.show();
```

use:

```
  DialogFragment newFragment = new FireMissilesDialogFragment();
  newFragment.show(getSupportFragmentManager(), "firemissile");
```

Comment: i did that but now im getting error "incompatible types", and that cant resolve method show with the given arguments

Comment: Then, in your MainActivity, instead of extending `Activity` , extend `FragmentActivity`